# VLC When the video list is played, a black screen remains for 1s

Tags: java, swing, vlc

When recirculating a playlist video, there will be a black screen for about 1 second each time a video is played while switching to the next video

version
vlcj: 3.8.0
java: 1.8.0_131 Oracle Corporation
vlc: 3.0.8 Vetinari, changeset 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7

```
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
             // loop play
            if (LIST_PROGRAM_PLAY_LOOP.equals(playMode)) {
                if (mrlList.size() == 1) {
                    mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
                } else {
                    if (++playIndex >= mrlList.size()) {
                        playIndex = 0;
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(mrlList.get(playIndex));
                    playingMrl = mrlList.get(playIndex);
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                }

            }
        }
}
```

On a computer with a core display, the problem will be more prominent, is there any way I can optimize it

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. One of the main developers mentioned in the [VLC forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=163540&p=540959&hilit=black%20screen#p540959) that you cannot do anything about it (except a massive refactoring of VLC itself)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find another solution. No longer through vlc itself.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend looking in OpenCV as an option.